# Add missing rows to a result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a fact and dim table

```
create table #fact (SKey int, HT varchar(5), TitleId int)

insert into #fact values
(201707, 'HFI', 1),
(201707, 'HFI', 3),
(201707, 'HFI', 5),
(201707, 'HFI', 6),
(201707, 'REO', 1),
(201707, 'REO', 2),
(201707, 'REO', 4),
(201707, 'REO', 5)

create table #dim (TitleId int, Title varchar(10))
insert into #dim values
(1, 'UK'),
(2, 'AF'),
(3, 'LQ'),
(4, 'AL'),
(5, 'GT'),
(6, 'ML')
```

using below query

```
select #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title
from #fact
    inner join #dim on #dim.TitleId = #fact.TitleId
order by #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title
```

which returns me following data

```
   SKey    HT    TitleId   Title  
 -------- ----- --------- ------- 
  201707   HFI         1   UK     
  201707   HFI         3   LQ     
  201707   HFI         5   GT     
  201707   HFI         6   ML     
  201707   REO         1   UK     
  201707   REO         2   AF     
  201707   REO         4   AL     
  201707   REO         5   GT
```

You see there are missing Titles in the result. for example, I don't have 'AF' and 'AL' for the first set ('HFI' set) and don't have 'LQ' and 'ML' for 'REO' part.

In summary I'm going to generate below result

```
   SKey    HT    TitleId   Title  
 -------- ----- --------- ------- 
  201707   HFI         1   UK     
  201707   HFI         2   AF     -- missing from first result
  201707   HFI         3   LQ     
  201707   HFI         4   AL     -- missing from first result
  201707   HFI         5   GT     
  201707   HFI         6   ML     
  201707   REO         1   UK     
  201707   REO         2   AF     
  201707   REO         3   LQ     -- missing from first result
  201707   REO         4   AL     
  201707   REO         5   GT     
  201707   REO         6   ML     -- missing from first result
```

currently I'm store the first result into a temp table and then use a loop/cursor to add missing rows into int.

Is there any way we use just one query to get the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a *cross join* like:

```
;with f as (
  select SKey, HT from fact
  group by SKey, HT
)
select f.SKey, f.HT, dim.TitleId, dim.Title 
from f, dim;
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7cc5b/6).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Why Ansi style joins are discouraged:https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to change that to an outer join.

```
select #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title
from #fact
    left join #dim on #dim.TitleId = #fact.TitleId
order by #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title
```

Comment: The rows will still be missing.  It doesn't have record to begin with in the left table.