# Add missing rows to result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I asked similar questions hour ago. [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104975/add-missing-rows-to-a-result-set/47106017#47106017)

This time situation is different

I have a fact and dim table. Comparing previous question, my fact table has an extra field called `Amount`

```
create table #fact (SKey int, HT varchar(5), TitleId int, Amount decimal(15,2))

insert into #fact values
(201707, 'HFI', 1, 15000),
(201707, 'HFI', 3, 16000),
(201707, 'HFI', 5, 17000),
(201707, 'HFI', 6, 18000),
(201707, 'REO', 1, 19000),
(201707, 'REO', 2, 20000),
(201707, 'REO', 4, 21000),
(201707, 'REO', 5, 22000)

create table #dim (TitleId int, Title varchar(10))
insert into #dim values
(1, 'UK'),
(2, 'AF'),
(3, 'LQ'),
(4, 'AL'),
(5, 'GT'),
(6, 'ML')
```

using below query

```
select #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title, #fact.Amount
from #fact
    inner join #dim on #dim.TitleId = #fact.TitleId
order by #fact.SKey, #fact.HT, #fact.TitleId, #dim.Title
```

which returns me following data

```
   SKey    HT    TitleId   Title    Amount   
 -------- ----- --------- ------- ---------- 
  201707   HFI         1   UK      15000.00  
  201707   HFI         3   LQ      16000.00  
  201707   HFI         5   GT      17000.00  
  201707   HFI         6   ML      18000.00  
  201707   REO         1   UK      19000.00  
  201707   REO         2   AF      20000.00  
  201707   REO         4   AL      21000.00  
  201707   REO         5   GT      22000.00
```

You see there are missing Titles in the result. for example, I don't have 'AF' and 'AL' for the first set ('HFI' set) and don't have 'LQ' and 'ML' for 'REO' part.

In summary I'm going to generate below result:

```
   SKey    HT    TitleId   Title    Amount   
 -------- ----- --------- ------- ---------- 
  201707   HFI         1   UK      15000.00  
  201707   HFI         2   AF          0.00  -- missing from first result
  201707   HFI         3   LQ      16000.00  
  201707   HFI         4   AL          0.00  -- missing from first result
  201707   HFI         5   GT      17000.00  
  201707   HFI         6   ML      18000.00  
  201707   REO         1   UK      19000.00  
  201707   REO         2   AF      20000.00  
  201707   REO         3   LQ          0.00  -- missing from first result
  201707   REO         4   AL      21000.00  
  201707   REO         5   GT      22000.00  
  201707   REO         6   ML          0.00  -- missing from first result
```

for missing rows I want to show Amound as 0.00

currently I'm store the first result into a temp table and then use a loop/cursor to add missing rows into int.

Is there any way we use just one query to get the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [previous suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104975/add-missing-rows-to-a-result-set/47106017#47106017) works for you, then you could do something similar by join the result back with the `fact` table, and use `coalesce` to replace *null* Amount with 0:

```
;with f as (
  select SKey, HT from fact
  group by SKey, HT
), combns as (
  select f.SKey, f.HT, dim.TitleId, dim.Title
  from f, dim
) 
select combns.*, coalesce(fact.Amount, 0) as Amount
from combns
left join fact 
on combns.SKey=fact.SKey and
   combns.HT=fact.HT and
   combns.TitleId=fact.TitleId
```

See the [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9f7f7/7).

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks again.